# I am getting below error when accessing FTP site

Tags: windows, ftp

```
530-User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
 Win32 error:   Access is denied.
 Error details: Authorization rules denied the access.
530 End
Login failed.
ftp>
```

This is my 2nd FTP site, 1st site is working fine. I gave read write permission to physical path to FTP user as well as in authorization rules
Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. You're gonna have to add a lot more detail to get a useful answer. Are you administering the FTP server? What server software does it run? What OS does the server run on? What are your authentication/authorization settings? etc. etc.

Comment: Yes I am administering  FTP Server, Windows Server 2012,only basic authentication enabled,authorization to allow my user